# Why is Get-ContainerNetwork not recognized as the name of a cmdlet on my Windows 10 box?

Tags: powershell, docker, nat

I'm new to docker, and am attempting to get my sql server image running under a predictable IP address.

Is this powershell command only for Windows Server?

PS> `Get-ContainerNetwork`

When I try running it, I only get the classic PowerShell error:

```
Get-ContainerNetwork : The term 'Get-ContainerNetwork' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ContainerNetwork
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ContainerNetwork:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Is it part of a module that's not loaded by default?

Comment: I'm just running powershell by typing it in my dumb-dumb search bar. I'm getting the sense from @Marcello's answer that there are different powershells. I have VS Code installed and Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise installed. So, in addition to whatever powershell my Win10 box started with (and whatever it may've been upgraded to after installing those IDE's) .. I'm just running whatever I get when I type "powershell" in the task bar /search gizmo

Comment: Modules contain a set of Powershell commands (more properly known as cmdlets) that have a common set of functionality, for example, the module used for managing Active Directory. Not all Modules are loaded by default when you open Powershell, and some (including the Active Directory module) must be imported using the Import-Module cmdlet. (Modules are, by the way, a fundamental concept within Powershell, so understanding the use of Modules is important to understanding Powershell.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, that you are trying to run deprecated PowerShell for Docker:

THIS MODULE HAS BEEN DEPRECATED -
Please note that due to low usage this module is no longer being actively maintained. It is recommended to use either the Docker cli (docker.exe) or try Docker.DotNet directly.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker-PowerShell

Comment: There's a lot of blog posts talking about setting up NAT and making Windows docker containers talk to one another that refer to this command. Do you have a good link that would point me to how/when this command was transitioned or phased out?

Comment: Would you say [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41615040/1520850) is all I need to accomplish my goal of making my SQL Server run on a predictable IP?